# Downgrade Windows 8 to Windows 7 from System Image

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, backup, downgrade

Recently i upgraded my laptop to Windows 8 from Windows 7. I am not happy with the performance of windows 8 and I want to downgrade it to windows 7.

I have a Windows Image Backup in my D:\ Drive and want to restore my laptop from that Image of windows 7, Is there any way of restoring my c drive from that image. Can I make a bootable hard drive from that Image which can be used to Re Image my laptop to windows 7.

The size of my Windows Image is 63 GB.

Comment: If it's an actual Windows image Backup made under Windows 7, then why not just restore it by the regular methods (boot from the Windows 7 disk, or repair disk you made with the Backup utility, and "repair your computer")?  If it's not, then how did you make the image?

Comment: What you want is not possible. The only way to move from Windows 8 to Windows 7 is to install Windows 7 on the Windows 8 partition. If you want to save the recovery partition that is a seperate task. Unless that image is from the same computer of course.  Perhaps its how you describe what you want, I would, clarify your question.

Comment: I am  unable to boot from my Windows 7 disk because i created it on a seperate partition in my hard drive and in my BIOS in booting options i only se my Hard drive and those partitions are not visible thats why i want to copy the the backup to an external hard drive, and i want to boot from that hard drive but i dont know how to copy my backup from my partition to an external hard drive

Comment: You can transfer the image file.  Its not clear what your trying to restore from ( at least from my perspective )

Answer (score 0):

Using Symantec Ghost 11 software you can reload your image for Windows 7

Copy Symatec Ghost 11 to a usb drive and locate the your image file through the cmd prompt.
Select `image to disk`